# Can't delete a group post using Facebook Graph API v3.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm doing a small PHP project for a university class which is supposed to be able to control a Facebook group. I managed to get reading posts and posting to the group through the API working but deletion isn't working for some reason. I've created the Facebook group from my personal account and I'm using a user access token to manage it.

I'm using the sample code provided here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/post#deleting

And I also tried debugging here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

But it always returns the following error: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".

All of the posts I'm trying this with are posted by my app. Even after getting a user access token which has ALL permissions possible, it still shows the same error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you read: "An app can delete any post it published, or a page-management app can delete a Post published to a Page that the app manages"? Did your app post it?

Comment: Yes, all of the posts I tried this with were posted by my app and it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure that’s possible for group posts. The permissions mentioned in the docs are all in regard to either user profile posts, or posts on pages (page itself or visitor.)

Comment: Well, the documentation says "An app can delete any post it published". No mentions of it not working for groups specifically, so I'd imagine there's a way.

Comment: Did you manage this problem? I have the same problem with removing posts from a group.